# How do I find Android Studios application MAKE file?

Tags: android, android-studio, makefile

I'm new to Android Studio so if anyone could tell me the STEPS how to find application Make file?

Im following the instructions on http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/4-0/guide/programming_practices/

Need to add below code to application make file

```
LOCAL_JAVA_LIBRARIES := com.symbol.emdk
LOCAL_PREBUILT_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES :=  libemdk:com.symbol.emdk/com.symbol.emdk.jar
```

Also, I check the settings editor->Inspections and it said Missing JNI Function. Not sure if this could be related.

I'm using a sample code but I get an error. I'm assuming its because I need to add the above code to the application make file.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.symbol.emdk.EMDKManager$EMDKListener" on path:
```

Answer (score 0):

In android studio, add following code in build.gradle

```
dependencies {  
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'], exclude: ['com.symbol.emdk.jar'])  
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'  
    provided files('./libs/com.symbol.emdk.jar')  
}
```

For more detail visit https://developer.zebra.com/thread/30509
In the above link clearly explained solution for eclispse and android studio both.

Comment: I did that before. I got 101 errors. So im using this example http://techdocs.zebra.com/emdk-for-android/4-0/tutorial/tutCreateProjectAndroidStudio/

Comment: Changed my file path but I get -- Observed package id 'add-ons;addon-symbol_emdk-symbol-19' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\hcanseco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-symbol-emdk_v4.0_API-19' (Expected 'C:\Users\hcanseco\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\add-ons\addon-symbol_emdk-symbol-19')